# How durable are the ancient weapons Cherry makes?

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild

At the Akkala Ancient Tech Lab, Robbie's machine, Cherry, can build several ancient weapons for you. They cost a lot in rupies *and* ancient parts. I'm really interested in the Ancient Bow, but don't want to drop the rupies, gears, and giant ancient core if the bow ever breaks or breaks as often as other bows. **How durable is the ancient bow Cherry makes?**

Comment: According to [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/301923/145980), there are no unbreakable weapons other than one specific weapon, so I would assume that the bow will break eventually. The real question is how long that will take. :)

Comment: I can't really answer it as I didn't count the number of hits I could do with my ancients weapons, but like all the other weapon in this game, they break too fast! But they are still good weapons so you just have to use them only when you're really in a pinch with a guardian haha.

Comment: Another thing that you might want to consider is how much guardian swag you can get per investment per item. My first purchase was the ancient shield, which I used almost exclusively to deflect guardian beams and collect their parts without attacking them. I was able to get a ton of parts with just one sheild, and had enough for the entire armor set after 2, plus the ancient bladesaw, plus 35 ancient arrows, which I've found sufficient enough to not warrant the ancient bow.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the specific case of the Ancient Bow, it is the most durable bow in the game without Amiibo items. It has a durability of 120, which for bows seems to be the number of shots it can fire, so 120.

Comment: Where did you get the 120 number? Is it visible in the game anywhere?

Comment: @splatteredbits none of this is in game, it is mostly just straight testing.

Comment: @splatteredbits It's in the Hardcover Game Guide.